# Recording an AudioTrack to a sound file

Tags: android, pcm, audiorecord

I am creating PCM data (from sine waves) and piping them to the speakers using AudioTrack.

I'd like to record this as a wav file (or a comparable format). I've looked at AudioRecord but it takes a source, and seems to want a microphone. Can I pipe my own PCM data into AudioRecord without a source so it saves my audio? Or is there another way to accomplish this.

Many thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you'll want to use the MediaRecorder as you already have the data and don't want to capture it. Rather you need to figure out a way to save the sine wave as a .WAV file and then you should be able to play that. I'm very interested in figuring out how to do this. I just haven't taken the time to figure it out yet.   Also if you accept answers on your  questions you'll be more likely to get answers on this and future questions.